# How can I reuse a thread? When are threads closed?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have this code:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!connected) {
            serverIpAddress = serverIp.getText().toString();
            if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
                Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                cThread.start();                   
            }
        }
    }
};

private OnClickListener communicateListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        message = messageServer.getText().toString();
        if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
            cThread.run();
            //Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
            //cThread.start();
        }                  

    }
};

public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {           
          if (socket==null)
              connect to the server;
          else
              do smth else;
    }
```

What I want is connectListener to create the thread and the thread to establish the connection. Then, on clicking communicateListener, the app would read from the socket or write into it. I don't know how to implement this.

Should I call the thread again somehow in the onclick method of communicateListener? Or is it continously running and it will "do smth else" when socket is other than null?

I tried calling again the run function but I got a NullPointerException. It works pretty fine when I create a new thread in communicateListener but I don't want to create a new thread each time I click on the button.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, never call a Thread's `run()` method; that will not run the code in a new thread, it runs it in your current thread. Call its `start()` method instead (to start a new thread that will soon be at the `run()` method).

When a thread runs out of code in the `run()` method (or explicitly returns out of the method), the thread is over. The object might still exist, allowing you to pull data from it (if there is anything you want), however the thread cannot be started again; you would need to create a new instance and start it instead.

If your intention is to create a thread once and let it "do other things" while waiting for real work to do, you can do that as well, but it's a different use model than "start up a new thread when I need my work done". Both use models have their place but the "start it when I need it" model is more simple to implement, and it's not terribly likely the efficiency given by the more complicated model is enough of a boost to matter when it's tied to UI actions.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you haven't read any documentation before trying to use them, because it's obvious that you have no understanding about threading in java. I would read the following chapter if I where you : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

But to sums things up, to make a thread work : you call "start()", and the thread will launch itself, and call the "run()" function.
When the run() function is over, the thread dies.

So, if you want to do the same action again, create a new instance of thread, and start it again.